# Probability of choosing 3 specific numbers out of numbers from $1$ to $22$

Tags: probability, combinations

There are numbers from $1$ to $22$ ($1$ and $22$ are included).If we randomly pick 3 numbers what is the probability that the absolute value of difference of any $2$ selected numbers is bigger than $5$?

I tried to solve it but I can't get the correct answer. So there are ${22 \choose 3}$= 1540 different ways to pick 3 numbers. Then I wanted to solve for when the difference is smaller than $5$ or equal to $5$ the subtract it from $1$ which I thought would be easier. But I make a mistake somewhere and can't find the mistake, nor the answer.I need help to find the answer

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempt.

Comment: "...that the absolute value of any two chosen numbers is bigger than $5$": the absolute value of what? Their difference?

Comment: Yes, I edited ,sorry

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we will arrange $19$ blue and $3$ green balls so that there are at least five blue balls between each pair of successive green balls.  Set $10$ blue balls aside.  That leaves $9$ blue and $3$ green balls to arrange.  In how many distinguishable ways can these $12$ balls be arranged?  Next, take the $10$ blue balls we set aside and insert five blue balls to the immediate right of each of the first two green balls to ensure that there are at least five blue balls between each pair of successive green balls.  Once the blue balls have been inserted, number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the desired set of three numbers which have the property that the absolute value of the difference of any two selected numbers is greater than $5$.

Comment: How do we know which number blue or green balls show

Comment: @Anar I think N. F. Taussig is suggesting numbering all the balls at the end from $1$ to $22$ and then looking at the numbers of the green balls.  But the numbers of final patterns satisfying your condition  is the answer to *"In how many distinguishable ways can these $12$ balls be arranged?"* (before numbering)  which you can then divide by your 22C3 to get your probability

Comment: @N. F. Taussig I understood "different ways of arranging 12 balls" but I couldn't really get the reason of part where we put 10 blue balls aside and "inserting 5 blue balls.

Comment: @Anar We set the blue balls aside so we can insert five blue balls to the right of each of the first two green balls.  That ensures that there are at least five blue balls between each pair of green balls.  Consequently, when we number the $22$ balls from left to right, the absolute value of the difference on the numbers between successive green balls will be greater than $5$.

Answer (score 0):

This really just the more precise way of writing NF Taussig's answer.

Given $1\leq a<b<c\leq 12,$ we can get a triple with your property, $\{a,b+5,c+10\}.$

In reverse, given $1\leq u<v<w<22$ where $v-u>5$ and $w-v>5$ we can get $a=u, b=v-5, c=w-10.$ (You need to show $a,b,c$ have the correct property: $1\leq a<b<c\leq 12.$)

So your set is in bijection with a set of size $\binom{12}{3}.$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach

As the OP (i.e original poster) analyzed, the probability is

$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{22}{3}.$$

So, the problem reduces to computing $N$, which represents the number of ways of selecting $3$ numbers, $~a_1,a_2,~$ and $~a_3~$ from the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,22\}~$ in such a way that :

$$|a_1 - a_2|, ~|a_1 - a_3|, ~|a_2 - a_3| > 5. \tag1 $$

---

The computation of $N$ may be construed to be a Stars and Bars problem.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Assume, without loss of generality, that $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$ and consider the following problem, which I will label **Problem-SB**:

**Problem-SB**: Compute the number of solutions to :

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = (22-3) = 19.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.
- $x_2, x_3 \geq 5.$

In effect, the selection of the three numbers $~a_1,a_2,~$ and $~a_3~$ from the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,22\}~$ create **four regions** (i.e. islands) of numbers within the set $~\{1,2,\cdots,22\}.~$

- The first region represents the set of numbers that are less than $~a_1.$
- The second region represents the set of numbers that are greater than $~a_1,~$ and less than $a_2.$
- The third region represents the set of numbers that are greater than $~a_2,~$ and less than $a_3.$
- The fourth region represents the set of numbers that are greater than $~a_3.$
- The variable $~x_i~$ represents the size of region $~i ~: ~i \in \{1,2,3,4\}.$

The constraints in (1) above will be satisfied if and only if $~x_2~$ and $~x_3~$ are each $~ \geq 5.$

---

Basic Stars and Bars theory gives that the number of solutions to

- $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$.
- $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.

is $\displaystyle \binom{n + [k-1]}{k-1}.$

So, to compute $~N,~$ **Problem-SB** must be **converted** into a form that fits the above pattern.  This may be done by the change of variables:

$y_2 = x_2 - 5, ~y_3 = x_3 - 5.$

Then, the number of solutions to **Problem-SB** is exactly the same as the number of solutions to:

- $x_1 + \color{red}{y_2 + y_3} + x_4 = (22-3) - (2 \times 5) = 9.$
- $x_1, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$.
- $y_2, y_3 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

That is, you will have $~y_2 \geq 0 \iff x_2 \geq 5,~$ and $~y_3 \geq 0 \iff x_3 \geq 5.$

Therefore,

$$N = \binom{9 + [4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{12}{3}.$$

Therefore, the probability is

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{\binom{12}{3}}{\binom{22}{3}}.$$